# $.post() in jQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, .post

I'm making a rating system, and I have the following jQuery code on my index.php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[id^=rating_]").hover(function() {

        var rid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
        $("#rating_"+rid).children("[class^=star_]").children('img').hover(function() {

            $("#rating_"+rid).children("[class^=star_]").children('img').removeClass("hover");

            /* The hovered item number */
            var hovered = $(this).parent().attr("class").split("_")[1];
            var hovered2 = $(this).parent().attr("class").split("_")[1];

            while(hovered > 0) {
                $("#rating_"+rid).children(".star_"+hovered).children('img').addClass("hover");
                hovered--;
            }

            $("#rating_"+rid).children("[class^=star_]").click(function() {
                var current_star = $(this).attr("class").split("_")[1];

                $.post("send.php", {rating: current_star, id: rid});
            });
        });

    });




});

</script>
```

Basically theres a hover effect and then when you click on the star, it'll send a post request to send.php, with the info on the rating clicked and the id of the element. Below this script I have some PHP that looks like this:

```
<?php


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rating = (int)$row[rating];
    ?>
    <div id="rating_<?php echo $row[id]; ?>">
    <span class="star_1"><img src="star_blank.png" alt="" <?php if($rating > 0) { echo"class='hover'"; } ?> /></span>
    <span class="star_2"><img src="star_blank.png" alt="" <?php if($rating > 1.5) { echo"class='hover'"; } ?> /></span>
    <span class="star_3"><img src="star_blank.png" alt="" <?php if($rating > 2.5) { echo"class='hover'"; } ?> /></span>
    <span class="star_4"><img src="star_blank.png" alt="" <?php if($rating > 3.5) { echo"class='hover'"; } ?> /></span>
    <span class="star_5"><img src="star_blank.png" alt="" <?php if($rating > 4.5) { echo"class='hover'"; } ?> /></span>
    <div class="clearleft">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <?php   
}

?>
```

And then of course I have some CSS to make it look nice.

The send.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());


$rating = (int)$_POST['rating'];
$id = (int)$_POST['rid'];



$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    if($rating > 5 || $rating < 1) {
        echo"Rating can't be below 1 or more than 5";
    }
    else {

        $total_ratings = $row['total_ratings'];
        $total_rating = $row['total_rating'];
        $current_rating = $row['rating'];

        $new_total_rating = $total_rating + $rating;
        $new_total_ratings = $total_ratings + 1;
        $new_rating = $new_total_rating / $new_total_ratings;


        // Lets run the queries. 

        mysql_query("UPDATE test SET total_rating = '".$new_total_rating."' WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE test SET rating = '".$new_rating."' WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE test SET total_ratings = '".$new_total_ratings."' WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
    }

}




?>
```

There are 3 rating columns in the database table;
total_rating: total ratings (all the ratings added together).
rating: the current rating
total_ratings: the amount of ratings.

The problem is, if I change the $_POST['rating'] and $_POST['rid'] to $_GET and put the information int he url, for instance, send.php?id=1&rating=4, it works, and the database gets updated. However, when I press the stars, the database isn't updated. After messing around with the script I realised that the post must be working, however the id returns as 0.

To test this further I put this in the click function:

```
document.write(current_star+rid);
```

To see what was returned. The problem seems to be that the number that is returned is multiplied by the amount of times I hover over elements. So if I hover over maybe, 6 of the stars, then the current_star and ID will be repeated 6 times.

I feel like I'm so close to getting this to work, has anyone got any idea what's up with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And important thing to realize about jQuery's event handling is that it is registry-based, meaning that jQuery allows you to register *multiple* callbacks for any particular event, and it will invoke them in the order in which they were bound.

The reason you're seeing repeated `current_star` and `id` values is because you keep binding more and more events on every hover.  This is because have your `click()` call inside your `hover()` call, therefore every time you hover, you will bind another click() event.

Try binding your `click()` event outside your hover event, using something like this:

```
$("[id^=rating_]").children("[class^=star_]").click(function() {
        var rid = $(this).parent().attr("id").split("_")[1];
        var current_star = $(this).attr("class").split("_")[1];

        $.post("send.php", {rating: current_star, id: rid});
});
```

You also probably don't want to bind one `hover()` call inside the other, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you have used `$_POST['rid']` instead of `$_POST['id']`. May be that's your problem.